# error while trying to do average on PANDA data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda data frame from csv file and i need to make a mean of 3 of the columns with the result in a new columns.
That is how the data looks like-

```
0      week     12    exp    exp    exp
1   Subject  Group      1      2      3
2       255   HD 0  117.4  104.8   87.0
3       418   WT 0   61.2   56.1   97.9
4       300   HD 0  111.7  126.9  118.4
5       299   HD 0   50.7   37.8   30.6
6       258   WT 0   56.0   67.9   58.5
7       173   HD 0   76.2  131.7  119.5
```

my code is -

```
with open('final results.csv', 'r') as frame:
    date_again = csv.reader(frame)   

    frame = []
    for line in date_again:
        frame = frame + [line]
panda_file = pd.DataFrame(frame)
```

panda_file['average'] = frame[3:].mean( axis=1)

The error i get is 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'mean'

How can i solve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First for create `DataFrame` use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with parameter `header=[0,1]`, because csv have 2 row header for `DataFrame` with `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""week,12,exp,exp,exp
Subject,Group,1,2,3
255,HD,0,117.4,104.8,87.0
418,WT,0,61.2,56.1,97.9
300,HD,0,111.7,126.9,118.4
299,HD,0,50.7,37.8,30.6
258,WT,0,56.0,67.9,58.5
173,HD,0,76.2,131.7,119.5"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), header=[0,1])

print (df)
       week    12    exp              
    Subject Group      1      2      3
255      HD     0  117.4  104.8   87.0
418      WT     0   61.2   56.1   97.9
300      HD     0  111.7  126.9  118.4
299      HD     0   50.7   37.8   30.6
258      WT     0   56.0   67.9   58.5
173      HD     0   76.2  131.7  119.5
```

Then select last 3 column for `mean`:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, -3:].mean(axis=1)
print (df1)
255    103.066667
418     71.733333
300    119.000000
299     39.700000
258     60.800000
173    109.133333
dtype: float64
```

And for new column need assign to tuples defined names of new MultiIndex column:

```
df[('exp', 'mean')] = df.iloc[:, -3:].mean(axis=1)
print (df)

       week    12    exp                          
    Subject Group      1      2      3        mean
255      HD     0  117.4  104.8   87.0  103.066667
418      WT     0   61.2   56.1   97.9   71.733333
300      HD     0  111.7  126.9  118.4  119.000000
299      HD     0   50.7   37.8   30.6   39.700000
258      WT     0   56.0   67.9   58.5   60.800000
173      HD     0   76.2  131.7  119.5  109.133333
```

---

But for simplify is possible flatten columns:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df)
    week_Subject  12_Group  exp_1  exp_2  exp_3
255           HD         0  117.4  104.8   87.0
418           WT         0   61.2   56.1   97.9
300           HD         0  111.7  126.9  118.4
299           HD         0   50.7   37.8   30.6
258           WT         0   56.0   67.9   58.5
173           HD         0   76.2  131.7  119.5

df['exp_mean'] = df.iloc[:, -3:].mean(axis=1)
print (df)
    week_Subject  12_Group  exp_1  exp_2  exp_3    exp_mean
255           HD         0  117.4  104.8   87.0  103.066667
418           WT         0   61.2   56.1   97.9   71.733333
300           HD         0  111.7  126.9  118.4  119.000000
299           HD         0   50.7   37.8   30.6   39.700000
258           WT         0   56.0   67.9   58.5   60.800000
173           HD         0   76.2  131.7  119.5  109.133333
```

Comment: @TalyaShacham - Do you use `df = pd.read_csv('final results.csv', header=[0,1])`?

Comment: I am trying to open it as you showed. It works fine with the temp but when i am putting my file name i am getting an error-

        df = pd.read_csv(pd.'final results.csv', header=[0,1])
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @TalyaShacham - there is typo - `pd.'final results.csv'`, need `'final results.csv'`